# What's the difference between the `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server(3.10.0-514.e17.x86_64) 7.3 (Maipo)` and `(0-rescue-bc0bxxxxx)`?

Tags: linux, rhel

When I install a CentOS in my Physical Server:

there list two options:

[image]

What's the difference between the `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server(3.10.0-514.e17.x86_64) 7.3 (Maipo)` and `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server(0-rescue-bc0bxxxxx)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line item in GRUB2 is a stripped-down OS used to recover when your standard OS (first line) will not boot. It [contains a valid installation tree](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode/), and the installation tree must be for the same version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux as the Red Hat Enterprise Linux disk from which you booted.